# Creating tables on fly with Spring Boot Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Trying to build application where tables & its fields are managed by master table & creation of tables & its fields happens on demand, on fly based on user data posted to server.
Tried to look over similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154401/creating-tables-on-demand-with-spring-boot-data-jpa) but wasnt able to find clue how to execute dynamic queries in DB without creating Repository & Entity in spring boot.

Comment: If you have dynamic tables JPA is the wrong approach. JPA is for static schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Robert Niestroj* is correct when he writes in the comments

> If you have dynamic tables JPA is the wrong approach. JPA is for static schema

I guess in theory you could do something where you generate code and possibly restart your `ApplicationContext` but it is bound to be really painful and you won't benefit from using JPA.

You should look into more dynamic technologies. MyBatis and plain old `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` come to my mind.
Possibly with your own abstraction layer on top of it if you have recurring scenarios.